# Does AppCode implement all the functionality of CLion

Tags: ide, clion, jetbrains-ide, appcode

The AppCode IDE home page states that:

> AppCode natively supports Objective-C, Swift,
> **C and C++,** including C++11, libc++ and Boost, as well as JavaScript,
> XML, HTML, CSS and XPath. Use your preferred language to create your
> iOS/OS X application.
>
> https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/

The CLion IDE is also meant for C and C++ but AppCode handles more languages.

**Does AppCode implement all the functionality of CLion?**

A yes answer I would think means it is better to go with AppCode.  An explanation against this is appreciated if you disagree.

Note: I have not yet used AppCode.

Answer (score 3):

Accordingly to various [comments](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-brand-new-ide-for-c-and-c-developers/#comment-62) / [forum threads](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5538492#5538492):

> The language support will be the same.
>
> Main differencies are in the tools support. For example, CLion has CMake build system and it is cross-platform.

Obviously, it's the case as long as you compare similar branches (e.g. builds on 142.xxx branch will have new stuff/fixes compared to 141.xxx). Build numbers can be checked on `About` screen.